# Do While Loop using InStr

Tags: excel, vba

The macro needs to loop through an variable number of rows (column A) and label them (in column B) regarding of four *InStr* search criteria.

If none of the four criteria are met, create a blank label and move on

My code looks like this, but is not working.

```
Sub LabelMaker() 
Dim rng As Range 
Set rng = ActiveCell 

Do While
ActiveCell.Value <> Empty 
If InStr(1, rng, "search criterion 1") Then
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Label 1" 
     ElseIf InStr(1, rng, "search criterion 2") Then
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Label 2"
```

.... and so forth

```
End If 
Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0) 
Loop 
End Sub
```

Comment: well, what's not working exactly? Additionally, I think this is a terrible way to iterate through the rows. You can get an int value for the last row via `LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` (that is for row 'A', declare 'LastRow' first). Then you use it as end critera for a for-loop. And don't use ActiveCell! Use `Cells(row, 1)` and `Cells(row, 2)` respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work for you? I have used EngJon's LastRow suggestion and put it into a working sub for you.

```
Sub MakeLabels()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim cl As Range

     Const dataCol As Long = 1

    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For Each cl In ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(2, dataCol), Cells(lastRow, dataCol))

        If InStr(1, cl.Value, "Search Crterion 1") Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Label 1"
        ElseIf InStr(1, cl, "Search Crterion 2") Then
            cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Label 2"
        Else
            cl.Offset(0, 1).Value = "Blank Label"
        End If

    Next cl


    End Sub
```